# Writing array to text file with tab delimiters, on one line

Tags: c#

I feel like this should be an easy question, but its totally bugging me. I have a string array, of size 64, called items. I want to write each item of items to a text file, with each value separated by a tab. When I try the following code though, it writes each item + tab, then a new line. How do I get all of the array written onto one line, instead of line by line?

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path1+custFile))
    for(int i=0; i<64; i++)
        file.WriteLine(items[i].ToString()+"\t");
```

Results:

```
1002H0025   
Sample test Customer    

Foo 
Mr  
123 FAKE STREET 

sAN JOSE
```

And so on and so on, and I excluded the tabs themselves from the above.
It should be
1002H0025   Sample test Customer    Foo Mr  123 FAKE STREET sAN JOSE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are currently using `WriteLine()` inside the loop.

Try using `Write()` instead.

`WriteLine` outputs a newline (`\n`) after it writes to the output.

Answer (score 4):

Well yes, look - you're calling this repeatedly:

```
file.WriteLine(items[i].ToString()+"\t");
```

As the name makes pretty clear, this writes a *line* - including line terminator. You *could* just change that to `file.Write`... but I would suggest getting rid of your loop entirely:

```
file.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", items));
```

Or get rid of the writer too:

```
string path = Path.Join(path1, custfile);
File.WriteAllText(path, string.Join("\t", items));
```

Comment: But then you are making one really long string and passing it into the file buffer.  Wouldn't it be better to just use the `file.Write` method?

Comment: @Trisped: Well, you say "one really long string" - it's 64 values being concatenated. Do you really think that's going to be a problem? I'd rather use the simple approach and handle it taking a few more K of memory. It would rarely be *significant*.

Comment: While 64 strings is probably not that big of a deal, there is a risk that the 64 is actually part of the "simplified" example code.

Comment: @Trisped: How often do you see a real life single-line text file which is *really* big enough to be a problem here?

Answer (score 0):

i need to save values in a text file using savefiledialog, everything works but iam unable to see all my ouput,only one line is visible.

```
   SaveFileDialog savefile = new SaveFileDialog();
   savefile.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
   if (savefile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
       using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(savefile.FileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
       using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
       {
           writer.WriteLine("northing:{0},easting:{1}", AE, AF);
           writer.Close();

       }
```

o/p obtained is northing:234567.89,easting:23456.89,other line is not visible

Comment: You could ask your own question instead.